# FB graph api cant figure out where to get my acces token

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I can figure out where to get my fb api acces token.

I got the code from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile

Now I filled in my app_id and my App_secret. But I also need to get an acces_token on this line:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
```

What is the acces token I need to fill in there and how can I obtain it?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'app-id',
    'app_secret' => 'app secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);


try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by the example that is a user access token. From the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens):

> The user token is the most commonly used type of token. This kind of
>   access token is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify
>   or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf. User
>   access tokens are [generally obtained via a login dialog and require a
>   person to permit your app to obtain one.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens)

Do you remember when an app shows a message like this?
[image: Facebook permission page]

At that moment, the app is asking Facebook for permission to provide him a user access token it will use in the future. User Access Tokens are user-dependant, meaning that you have to request an access token for every user of your app.

That process is better explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens